# Is there a list of the services compatible with New Twitter’s sidebar?

Tags: twitter

Services like yfrog, YouTube, and gist.github.com can be displayed in the right sidebar of New Twitter, if a user includes a link to them in a tweet.

Is there a place where I can see a list of the services that are supported by this sidebar extension?

Comment: It displays gists? That's actually pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a couple different lists for this.

[Twitter list of photo/video supported sites](http://tos-proxy.appspot.com/support.twitter.com/articles/75603-how-to-post-photos-videos-on-twitter):  Twitpic, Flickr, Yfrog, Twitgoo, Plixi, YouTube, Vimeo, Twiddeo, Ustream, Justin.tv, Twitlens, Tweetube, Twitvid

[TechCrunch Article](http://techcrunch.com/2010/09/15/twitter-mini-platform/):  Dailybooth, DeviantArt, Etsy, Flickr, Justin.TV, Kickstarter, Kiva, Photozou, Plixi, Twitgoo, TwitPic, Twitvid, USTREAM, Vimeo, Yfrog, and YouTube